# Question about using an integral to calculate surface area and volume of a sphere.(dL instead of dx)

Tags: integration, geometry

Why is it wrong to calculate the surface area of a sphere using $2\int_0^R 2πr dx$?
Why is $dA$ equals to $2πrdL$ and not $2πrdx$ ?
Why is $dS$ equals to $πr^2dx$ and not $πr^2dL$?

Comment: roughly speaking, $dx$ is a flat infinitesimal piece, whereas $dL$ is scaled and curved to look like a piece of a circle, which is what slices of a sphere look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the surface area of a slice of a cylinder and a slice of a sphere  is that the first one is flat and the second one is curved.

The $dx$ works for the cylinder but $dL$ is needed to express the curved surface of the slice of the sphere.

For the volume however the volume of the slice of the sphere is approximated by the volume of a cylindrical slice so $dx$ is used for both.( It is the radius which changes for the sphere and stays fixed for the cylinder.)